# Twilio Numbers Stuck in "Free Mode" After Switching To Paid

Tags: twilio

I'm developing a Twilio-based service.  I've got 10 numbers in "paid" mode account on Twilio, but I'm still getting the "press X, Y to continue" before each call.

I put in a ticket days ago with Twilio (5 calendar, 3 business) but nothing from Twilio so far.  Any ideas about why I'm getting this message before my call goes through?

My project uses naked (no helper lib) TWIML being sent back from a Laravel project running (dev mode) on a ngrok connection to my dev laptop.  In terms of "working" the Dial verb works, I get my action and recording status msgs, its all just fine.

Comment: What do you mean before each call? do you mean when you call the number it states that?

Comment: Can you drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com with your ticket ID and I'll try to chase this up for you.

Comment: When I make a call from my cell to the number in test, I get a voice prompt "To complete the call, press <random digit>, <random digit>".  Its typical of a free trial situation.